# Help Identifying PVC Drain Connector Type

Tags: plumbing

I need help.  Can anyone help me identify this type of connection currently used under my bathroom sink?  All I can find are threaded pipe connections.   Unfortunately my wall connection is this same type of twist/lock connector.    Any help you can provide that will help me locate replacement parts that utilize this type of connector would be greatly appreciated.
[image: Pic of the current connection type]

Comment: Some company designer had fun one day so people would be locked into their products.  Can you see a company name on that pipe?  Your general location might help also, since those pipes might be in a local region.

Comment: I'm in Charlotte North Carolina area.. I'll see if I can find a name.

Comment: Says "Bayonet™" molded in the upper left of the picture. I'd rip it out until I hit normal pipe and replace with normal slip-joint drain fittings, most likely.

Comment: Your local plumbing shops should be able to help also, unlikely you are the only local to have that type.

Comment: Thank you all.. very helpful. Found the product
https://www.jb-products.com/product/bayonet-p-traps-pvc/

The current plumbing is basically "on the wall" no room to cut and replace.  So i'm likely just going to splice  the old connector to the new one so I can use the more standard connections.  Again I appreciate all the help!

Comment: If you'll take the [tour], you'll note the proper way of saying "thanks" is to up vote any/all answers that help you and click the check mark on the one that helped you the most.

Comment: thanks.. I hovered over the flag arrow looking to mark the answers that helped. I guess the up arrow just didn't stick out as much :)  Thanks for the direction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image: Detail showing logo]

Apparently it's this https://www.jb-products.com/product/bayonet-p-traps-pvc/

I'd cut the oddball thing out, unless you actually find it in stock at a local hardware store.

While it connects to PVC, you can see from the text around the name that, like most white plastic traps that are not glued, it's polypropylene (PP) except for the bit that glues to the PVC pipe.

Comment: OP's problem may be if the elbow with the respective locking ring is glued to the wall stub.  But still hopefully not an insurmountable issue.